# Display value on the bar chart

Tags: delphi

I want to know how to display value(in percent) on the bar series[image]

Thanks..

Answer (score 7):

Use ArrowLength properties of marks and give negative value. For example:

```
TheChart.Series[0].Marks.ArrowLength := -60;
TheChart.Series[1].Marks.ArrowLength := -60;
TheChart.Series[2].Marks.ArrowLength := -60;
```

[image]